# Converting sentences into propositional logic

Tags: math

I am looking for a program or web service that can convert sentences into propositional logic, if possible running on Windows or Linux and open source.

[Examples](http://www.bu.edu/linguistics/UG/course/lx502/_docs/lx502-propositional%20logic.pdf):

- Let p = It is raining
- Let q = Mary is sick

Then:

- "It is not the case that Mary isn’t sick" should be converted into "¬¬q"
- "It is raining and Mary is sick"  should be converted into "p ∧ q"
- "If it is raining, then Mary is sick"should be converted into "p → q"

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the sort of thing that you should be investigating python natural language toolkit, ([nltk](http://www.nltk.org/)), and [sci-kit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) for.  They are free, multi-platform and open source.